# How to set the count property of a related entity without having to perform an extra query or include unnecessary data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a class "Campaign" that has a navigation property "Students".  The campaign class has an attribute "StudentsCount" to store the amount of students.  I do not want to include all the students in the query results.  How can I query for campaigns while attaching their respective student counts?  I ideally do not want to iterate through all my campaigns after the initial query to grab the counts.

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = this._objectSet.AsQueryable(); //this is my campaigns object set
query = query.Where(c => c.UserId == id);
query = query.Include("");
return query.ToArray();
```

Update: --
Please note that my initial query is grabbing more than one campaign

I'm thinking maybe I could do something with a select but I am not exactly sure how to accomplish this

Comment: One of my favourite Entity Framework questions to ask in interviews!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a computed column with sql onto the Campaign Table.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getStudentCount(@studentCount int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r int
    select @r = COUNT(*) from Student where CampaignId = @studentCount
    RETURN @r
END
GO

ALTER TABLE Campaign ADD StudentCount AS dbo.getStudentCount(Id)
```

this automatically sets the column to be a generated attribute in the EDMX.

Answer (score 1):

Querying for counts without loading the collection of child items is called an `extra lazy` query if you need the term to allow you to Google around this.

In this case, you would do something like this:

```
var campaign = query.Single();
var studentsQuery = context.Entry(campaign).Collection(c => c.Students).Query();
var count = studentsQuery.Count();
```

This will materialise the count of entities without bringing them all back.

Comment: cool! so..to be annoying, how would i handle this if I was grabbing many Campaigns in one query?  Would I need to have a studentcount query for each Campaign?

Comment: The best Ive ever been able todo is iterate over each parent and perform a count query per entity. If I needed todo this under any kind of load I would probably rearchitect this as some kind of report (i.e. denormalise and periodically calculate the aggregates)